# How To Add multiple Button Selections to a Div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I have A Table With Buttons and match information, I am trying to script a code when I click on the specific button, it adds my selections to div(cart) for example if i click on the first button (1.59), it should add the match Name to the cart (Arsenal-Chelsea) ,The related selection (Arsenal) OR Header Name (Home) and The Value (1.59) in this order

Arsenal-Chelsea
Arsenal
1.59

Plus, I need it to be functional whenever I Re-click on the same button (1.59) it should be able to remove the selection from the cart

```js
$(".nr").click(function() {
  var $item = $(this).closest("tr").find(".nr").val();
  $("#cart").append($item);
  $("#cart").append("<div class='cart' Id='cart'>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javscript" src="script.js"></script>

<div class="cart" Id="cart">
  <div class="title">Bet Slip</div>
  <chr/>
  <div id="sel"><span></span></div><br>
  <span>Selections:</span><br>
  <button class="bet1">Bet</button><br>
</div>
<br>
<table id="choose-address-table" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
      <th>Match</th>
      <th>Home</th>
      <th>Draw</th>
      <th>Away</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Arsenal-Chelsea</td>
      <td><input type=button class="nr" value="1.59"></td>
      <td><input type=button class="nr" value="3.40"></td>
      <td><input type=button class="nr" value="2.90"></td>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Man United-Man City</td>
      <td><input type=button class="nr" value="2.70"></td>
      <td><input type=button class="nr" value="2.90"></td>
      <td><input type=button class="nr" value="2.50"></td>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Barcelona-Real Madrdid</td>
      <td><input type=button class="nr" value="3.60"></td>
      <td><input type=button class="nr" value="3.20"></td>
      <td><input type=button class="nr" value="1.95"></td>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour to get a better understanding about https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Another good read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions?. Afterwards, please edit your question to add all the relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use DOM traversal to find the content related to the button which was clicked. To get the venue you can get the index of the containing `td` and then retrieve the matching `thead th` which holds the text. To get the match you can get the text of the first `td` in the current row.

When appending the new content, don't use `id` attributes as they must be unique.

Also note in the following example that I fixed some of the issues in your HTML, such as extra `</td>` tags and removing the `<chr />` tag, which doesn't exist.

```js
let $th = $('#choose-address-table thead th');

$(".nr").on('click', e => {
  let $btn = $(e.target);
  let $option = $(`.cart[data-id="${$btn.prop('id')}"]`);
  if ($option.length) {
    $option.remove();
    return;
  }
  
  let $tr = $btn.closest('tr');
  let selectionIndex = $btn.closest('td').index();

  let match = $tr.find('td:first').text().trim();
  let result = $th.eq(selectionIndex).text().trim();
  let value = $btn.val();
  $("#cart").append(`<div class="cart" data-id="${$btn.prop('id')}">${match} ${result} ${value}</div>`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<div class="cart" Id="cart">
  <div class="title">Bet Slip</div>
  <div id="sel"><span></span></div><br />
  <span>Selections:</span><br />
  <button class="bet1">Bet</button><br />
</div><br />
<table id="choose-address-table" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr class="ui-widget-header">
      <th>Match</th>
      <th>Home</th>
      <th>Draw</th>
      <th>Away</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Arsenal-Chelsea</td>
      <td><input type="button" class="nr" value="1.59" id="option_0_0" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" class="nr" value="3.40" id="option_0_1" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" class="nr" value="2.90" id="option_0_2" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Man United-Man City</td>
      <td><input type="button" class="nr" value="2.70" id="option_1_0" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" class="nr" value="2.90" id="option_1_1" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" class="nr" value="2.50" id="option_1_2" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Barcelona-Real Madrdid</td>
      <td><input type="button" class="nr" value="3.60" id="option_2_0" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" class="nr" value="3.20" id="option_2_1" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" class="nr" value="1.95" id="option_2_2" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Good, but now when I need the code to also remove the same selection when I re-click on the recent button as in removing the selection

Comment: can you please edit the code to also remove the same selection when I re-click on the recent button as in removing the selection

Comment: To do that you can add an `id` to the buttons to use to identify them. Then you can toggle the output that's generated based on that id. I've updated the answer to show you how to do that.

Comment: So add the `id` to the HTML generated in the PHP..?

Comment: Okay, Since now im using the echo function, the button Id keeps repeating and only limited to the first three id ,how do i create unique id for every button in case of using echo in php

Comment: Increment the variable within the loop and append that to the HTML output. If you're struggling with it, I'd suggest starting a new question